# using complete after jquery animation not working

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a jQuery function that animates a div overlay. On completion of the animation I want a `.load` function to happen. I was trying to do this using the complete function, but can't seem to get it working.

```
$(function() {
    $("#fullscreen_launch").click(function(){
        $("#fullscreen").animate({
            top: '0px',
            height:'100%',
        }, 950),
        complete: function() {
            $('#fullscreen').load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: please fix your indentation - it's hard to read your code like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.animate()` has two different syntax options that you cannot just mix.

```
.animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )

.animate( properties, options )
```

In the first case, it would look like this

```
$("#fullscreen").animate({
    top: '0px',
    height:'100%',
}, 950, function() {
    $('#fullscreen')
       .load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
});
```

Comment: so with this, now the animation doesn't happen anymore.                                                            <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#fullscreen_launch").click(function(){
$("#fullscreen").animate({
    top: '0px',
    height:'100%',
}, 950, function() {
    $('#fullscreen')
       .load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');

});
</script>

Comment: okay so this works, but the problem I run into now, is the page it's loading through .load is a slider (you can see it if you go to the url) is when it loads the slider it doesn't load the images in it the first time, but the second time you click the button it does load the images, any ideas why this happens?

Comment: please be very careful about matching your parentheses and brackets. There are missing closing brackets and an added semicolon that doesn't belong there

Comment: btw this is what I'm using, it works, but the above problem is happening: <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#fullscreen_launch").click(function(){
$("#fullscreen").animate({
    top: '0px',
    height:'100%',
}, 950, function() {
    $('#fullscreen')
       .load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
});
});
});
</script>

Comment: The problem of the slider describes a different problem. Please open a new entry for it with your full changed code